# Probability and correlation of two uniform discrete and independent random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following problem:

We have two random variables, discrete, uniform and independent

$x=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$

$y=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$

Find:

1. $P(X+Y=5)$ where I have calc $P(X+Y=5)=\frac{1}{20}$
2. $P(X>Y)$
3. Correlation between X and Y

I have calc the first problem but now how can I solve the other two point? I have no idea about the method for the solution.

Any help is accepted.

Thank you

Comment: For 1. you presumably added up four cases of $\frac1{80}$.  For 2. you can take the same approach, though there are many more cases to add up

Comment: For 3. there is a clue in the introduction *"We have two random variables, discrete, uniform and independent"*

Comment: In the second question, the probability you need to find is equal to $P(X-Y>0)$. Can you find this probability? And the last one, generally you need to compute the means and the variance of both random variables and the covariance between them. Do you know anything about a covariance of two independent random variables?

Comment: yes, covariance=0 for independent random variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For b), you need to find $P(X-Y>0) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}P(X-Y>0|X=k)(X=k) = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=0}^{10}P(X-Y>0|X=k)$

For c), if the rvs are independent, their covariance$=0$

Comment: Thanks Alex, the first request is ok for you? For the point b, your version is the last? because is an iterative process right?

Comment: You should add more details

Comment: I have created a table with all the combination and I have find $\frac{4}{80}=\frac{1}{20}$

Comment: Keep in mind $5=4+1=3+2=2+3=1+4$

Comment: Yes, can I use the same method for $P(X-Y>0)$? It's really user friendly

Comment: You need to account only for cases when $X>Y$, which obviously, e.g. $2+3$ and $3+2$ do not